# New to Common Lisp and can't understand why the defun function is not working in simple case

Tags: common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

In Chapter 3 of "Practical Common Lisp," we are asked to create a CD database by creating the function `make-cd` which is defined as follows:

```
(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))
```

Within my REPL (using SLIME) this seems to go according to plan... until I come to add a value to the database, e.g.

```
(make-cd "Roses" "Kathy Mattea" 7 t)
(:TITLE "Roses" :ARTIST "Kathy Mattea" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T)
```

Then I get the following error message

```
Undefined function :TITLE called with arguments ("Roses"
                                             :ARTIST
                                             "Kathy Mattea"
                                             :RATING
                                             7
                                             :RIPPED
                                             T) .
   [Condition of type CCL::UNDEFINED-FUNCTION-CALL]
```

This code is character-for-character what is written in the book and there is no note to explain the error, or what this error means.

I am new to Lisp and have no idea what has gone wrong here!

Comment: make-cd returns a list. The error states that you are then trying to eval the list. The first element is not a valid function.

Comment: You’re missing a paren at the end of your first listing

Answer (score 7):

in the book the instruction to add an entry to the database is:

```
CL-USER> (make-cd "Roses" "Kathy Mattea" 7 t)
```

`CL-USER>` is the prompt of the REPL, followed by your input.

the line that follows is does not start with a prompt and indicates the output that the function call returns:

```
(:TITLE "Roses" :ARTIST "Kathy Mattea" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T)
```

you should only enter the first line, then verify that the output you get matches the second line.